# Xamarin Forms Maps Circle Custom Renderer

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Experiencing two issues with a custom map/renderer on iOS.

Demo video: https://ufile.io/pscn3

I have a custom map class with a circle that is placed on the map.
A slider control resizes the circle from a bindable property.

1. When slider value changes, the circle's radius property gets updated with the selected value. But as you can see, it's not updating the radius on map, instead it moves the circle to new positions within a curve.
2. When the circle is moved outside x pixels, it disappears or gets cut off outside the visible bounds.

These are the classes being used:

Page.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CompanyName.Data.ViewModels.MapWithCircleSlider;assembly=CompanyName"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CompanyName.UI;assembly=CompanyName"
    x:Class="CompanyName.UI.Pages.MapWithCircleSlider"
    Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:MapWithCircleSliderViewModel></vm:MapWithCircleSliderViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <local:CircleMap Grid.Row="0" CircleRadius="{Binding CircleRadius}" Latitude="{Binding Latitude}" Longitude="{Binding Longitude}" MapRadius="{Binding MapRadius}" IsShowingUser="true" HasZoomEnabled="true" />
                <!--<Image Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="ic_place_green_48dp.png" />-->
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="32,16">
                    <Entry VerticalOptions="Start" Placeholder="navn *" Text="{Binding Name}">
                        <Entry.Style>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Style">
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="{x:Static local:Styling.IosEntryStyle}" />
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Entry.Style>
                    </Entry>
                    <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding CircleRadius, StringFormat='{0}m'}" />
                    <Slider VerticalOptions="End" Maximum="{Binding Maximum}" Minimum="{Binding Minimum}" Value="{Binding CircleRadius}" />
                    <!-- NB: Maximum must be set before Minimum, ref: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23665 -->
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Pages ViewModel:

```
using System;
using CompanyName.ViewModels;

namespace CompanyName.Data.ViewModels.MapWithCircleSlider
{
    public class MapWithCircleSliderViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private string name;
        private int circleRadius;
        private float latitude;
        private float longitude;
        private int mapRadius;

        public MapWithCircleSliderViewModel()
        {
            Name = "Labs";
            CircleRadius = 200;
            MapRadius = 200;
            Latitude = 58.9698634f;
            Longitude = 5.7331874f;
        }

        public int Maximum => 1000;
        public int Minimum => 100;
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsEditMode { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set
            {
                if (name == value) return;

                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public int CircleRadius
        {
            get => circleRadius;
            set
            {
                if (circleRadius == value) return;

                circleRadius = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CircleRadius");
            }
        }

        public float Latitude
        {
            get => latitude;
            set
            {
                if (Math.Abs(latitude - value) < float.Epsilon) return;

                latitude = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Latitude");
            }
        }

        public float Longitude
        {
            get => longitude;
            set
            {
                if (Math.Abs(longitude - value) < float.Epsilon) return;

                longitude = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Longitude");
            }
        }

        public int MapRadius
        {
            get => mapRadius;
            set
            {
                if (mapRadius == value) return;

                mapRadius = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MapRadius");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CircleMap.cs

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace CompanyName.UI
{
    public class CircleMap : Map
    {
        private const int DefaultCircleRadius = 100;
        private const float DefaultLatitude = 58.8523208f;
        private const float DefaultLongitude = 5.7326743f;
        private const int DefaultMapRadius = 150;

        public static readonly BindableProperty CircleRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CircleRadius", typeof(int), typeof(CircleMap), DefaultCircleRadius, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnCircleRadiusPropertyChanged);
        public static readonly BindableProperty LatitudeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Latitude", typeof(float), typeof(CircleMap), DefaultLatitude, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnLatitudePropertyChanged);
        public static readonly BindableProperty LongitudeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Longitude", typeof(float), typeof(CircleMap), DefaultLongitude, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnLongitudePropertyChanged);
        public static readonly BindableProperty MapRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MapRadius", typeof(int), typeof(CircleMap), DefaultMapRadius, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnMapRadiusPropertyChanged);

        public CircleMap() : base(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(DefaultLatitude, DefaultLongitude), Distance.FromMeters(DefaultMapRadius))) { }

        public int CircleRadius
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(CircleRadiusProperty);
            set => SetValue(CircleRadiusProperty, value);
        }

        public float Latitude
        {
            get => (float)GetValue(LatitudeProperty);
            set => SetValue(LatitudeProperty, value);
        }

        public float Longitude
        {
            get => (float)GetValue(LongitudeProperty);
            set => SetValue(LongitudeProperty, value);
        }

        public int MapRadius
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(MapRadiusProperty);
            set => SetValue(MapRadiusProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnCircleRadiusPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var circleMap = (CircleMap)bindable;
            circleMap.CircleRadius = (int)newValue;
        }

        private static void OnLatitudePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var circleMap = (CircleMap)bindable;
            circleMap.Latitude = (float)newValue;

            MoveToRegion(circleMap);
        }

        private static void OnLongitudePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var circleMap = (CircleMap)bindable;
            circleMap.Longitude = (float)newValue;

            MoveToRegion(circleMap);
        }

        private static void OnMapRadiusPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var circleMap = (CircleMap)bindable;
            circleMap.MapRadius = (int)newValue;

            MoveToRegion(circleMap);
        }

        private static void MoveToRegion(CircleMap circleMap)
        {
            circleMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(circleMap.Latitude, circleMap.Longitude), Distance.FromMeters(circleMap.MapRadius)));
        }
    }
}
```

CustomMapRenderer.cs (iOS):

```
using CompanyName.UI;
using MapKit;
using ObjCRuntime;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using CompanyName.iOS.Renderers.CustomRenderer;
using CompanyName.Utilities;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CircleMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace CompanyName.iOS.Renderers.CustomRenderer
{
    /// <remarks>
    /// https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/circle-map-overlay/#Creating_the_Custom_Renderer_on_iOS
    /// </remarks>
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        private CircleMap circleMap;
        private MKCircleRenderer circleRenderer;
        private MKMapView NativeMap => Control as MKMapView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);

                if (e.OldElement != null)
                {
                    if (Control is MKMapView nativeMap)
                    {
                        nativeMap.RemoveOverlays(nativeMap.Overlays);
                        nativeMap.OverlayRenderer = null;
                        circleRenderer = null;
                    }
                }

                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    circleMap = (CircleMap)e.NewElement;
                    NativeMap.OverlayRenderer = GetOverlayRenderer;

                    AddOverlay();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Logger.LogException(ex, GetType().Name);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (sender == null) return;
            circleMap = (CircleMap)sender;

            if (e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion") OnVisibleRegionChanged();
            if (e.PropertyName == CircleMap.CircleRadiusProperty.PropertyName) RedrawOverlay();
        }

        private MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
        {
            if (circleRenderer == null && !Equals(overlayWrapper, null))
            {
                var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;
                circleRenderer = new MKCircleRenderer(overlay as MKCircle)
                {
                    Alpha = 0.15f,
                    FillColor = CompanyName.Constants.Colors.Skobeloff500.ToUIColor(),
                    LineWidth = 1,
                    StrokeColor = CompanyName.Constants.Colors.Skobeloff500.ToUIColor()
                };
            }
            return circleRenderer;
        }

        private void OnVisibleRegionChanged()
        {
            SetNewCoordinates();
            RedrawOverlay();
        }

        private void SetNewCoordinates()
        {
            circleMap.Latitude = (float)circleMap.VisibleRegion.Center.Latitude;
            circleMap.Longitude = (float)circleMap.VisibleRegion.Center.Longitude;
            circleMap.MapRadius = (int)circleMap.VisibleRegion.Radius.Meters;
        }

        private void RedrawOverlay()
        {
            RemoveOverlays();
            AddOverlay();
        }

        private void RemoveOverlays()
        {
            if (NativeMap?.Overlays == null) return;
            if (NativeMap.Overlays.Any()) NativeMap.RemoveOverlays(NativeMap.Overlays);
        }

        private void AddOverlay()
        {
            var circleOverlay = MKCircle.Circle(new CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2D(circleMap.Latitude, circleMap.Longitude), circleMap.CircleRadius);
            NativeMap.AddOverlay(circleOverlay);
        }
    }
}
```

Any feedback / suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to refresh the `circleRenderer` to achieve your effect like:

```
private void RemoveOverlays()
{
    if (NativeMap?.Overlays == null) return;
    if (NativeMap.Overlays.Any())
    {
        NativeMap.RemoveOverlays(NativeMap.Overlays);

        circleRenderer = null;
        NativeMap.OverlayRenderer = GetOverlayRenderer;
    }
}
```